# Chatbot automatic reply flask

Tags: python, flask

I am working on webapp that simulates an interview session. After session finishes chatbot should display message.
my frontend is js and backend is python flask.
chatbot should send message without user response, it should initiate.
my problem is backend function works properly but it prints reply in console rather than chatbot interface.

```
@app.route("/post_interview", methods = ['POST'])
def chat_reply():
    print("in_post")
    response = get_response("results")
    print(response)
    message ={"answer":response}
    return jsonify(message)
```

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Print function only works for the console, it's normal you don't see it in the screen. To render html to your webpage you must use `render_template()`.

Here is an example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index(): # renders index.html that is inside templates folder
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Now when you access the url of your website you will see the html in `index.html`

Comment: I already have render template to my index.html, it is not working

Comment: Have you created  a index.html file in a folder in the same directory as your app file called templates?

Comment: Yes I have I think the problem might be in the chat.py thanks anyway.